# Why is there an error for the third let-in statement?

Tags: haskell

`Prelude> let [x,y] = [3,4] in x*x+y*y`

> `25`

`Prelude> let x:[y] = [3,4] in x*x + y*y`

> `25`

`Prelude> let x:y = 3:4 in x*x+y*y`

> interactive:6:5: error:
>       * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
>         (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
>       * When checking the inferred type
>           x :: forall a. (Num a, Num [a]) => a
>         In the expression: let x : y = 3 : 4 in x * x + y * y
>         In an equation for `it': it = let x : y = 3 : 4 in x * x + y * y

Can someone explain what is happening in the first two statements and why is there an error for the third `let ... in ..` statement.

Comment: Unfortunately the error is not clear but the cause is: `:` is an operator to build lists with the type `a -> [a] -> [a]` so it needs a list in the right hand: `let x:y = 3:[4] in x*x+y*y`. Note that you cant use y as a number cause

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found the answer myself :)
It is because: `prepend operator` adds something to a list. Here there was no list!
It can be solved by doing `let x:y:[] = 3:4:[] in x*x+y*y OR let x:[y] = 3:[4] in x*x+y*y`

Comment: Please post an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted (after a wait time). This is how StackOverflow is supposed to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the third example, the right-hand-side of the `let` assignment is: `3:4`. The `:` (cons) operator has the type signature `a -> [a] -> [a]`: it takes a value on its left side, and a list of that type of value on the right side. In this case, `3` is an `a`, but `4` is not a list of `a` (`[a]`); it is also an `a`. This is invalid.

Given the form of your exercise so far, there are two ways that you can fix this expression: with `3:[4]` or with `3:4:[]`.

If you tried running your code now, you would see that it fails on `x * x + y * y`. This is because your pattern-match assigns `x` to `3`, and `y` to `[4]` (a singleton list). A list cannot be multiplied by itself, nor can it be added to a number. So once more, we use the solution for the right-hand-side, on the left-hand-side:

```
let x:y:[] = 3:4:[]
    in x * x + y * y
```

If we add a few too many type annotations, you can hopefully see where things are going wrong:

```
-- These work fine
-- let [x, y] = [3, 4] in ...
example1 = let [(x :: a), (y :: a)] :: [a]
             = [(3 :: a), (4 :: a)] :: [a]
            in x * x + y * y
-- let x:[y] = [3, 4] in ...
example2 = let ((x :: a) : ([(y :: a)] :: [a])) :: [a]
            in x * x + y * y

-- This is the incorrect implementation
-- let x:y = 3:4 in ...
example3 :: (Num a) => a
example3 = let (x :: a) : (y :: [a])   -- (:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
             = (3 :: a) : (4 :: a)     -- 4 :: a is invalid here: require [a]
            in (x :: a) * (x :: a)
             + (y :: [a]) * (y :: [a]) -- Trying to multiply two lists

-- This is the fixed implementation
-- let x:y:[] = 3:4:[] in ...
example3' :: (Num a) => a
example3' = let ((x :: a) : (y :: a) : ([] :: [a])) :: [a]
              = ((3 :: a) : (4 :: a) : ([] :: [a])) :: [a]
             in x * x + y * y
```